# Headless bluetooth pairing with PIN and making it non-discoverable after pairing

Tags: raspbian, bluetooth

I have used simple-agent found on this [link](https://github.com/artynet/Bluez/blob/master/test/simple-agent),

I wanted to use my Raspberry Pi heedlessly, hence I have hardcoded a specific pin in the code, instead of returning the value entered on the Raspberry Pi screen. But even though I enter the pin I hardcoded, it still returns "Incorrect Pin" message on my phone. How do I trouble-shoot this issue?

Also, is it possible to make the RaspberryPi undiscoverable after pairing with just one device?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: please include the code you have used, and the steps you have taken, with so little information, it will be very difficult for anyone to help you.